# angularjs $watch not work in my item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

```
<input ng-model="myInput"
       type="email"
       placeholder="Recipient" />
```

**controller :**

```
$scope.myInput = 3;
  $scope.$watch('myInput', function() {
         console.log(1); 
     });
```

when I input something in `console.log(1)`,not work!

Comment: Did you add your controller as `ng-controller` to one of input's parent elements and`ng-model="myInput"` to your input?

Comment: Could you include a more complete code sample, for instance, all of your HTML and controller code? What you have posted looks correct.  Perhaps try replicating the problem at http://jsfiddle.net/ first.

Answer (score 1):

`$watch` will execute only if `myInput` has valid email value .if it don't have valid email then myInput seems like undefined.that is the reason `$watch` is not execute.so put valid email in that field and then check it is executing or not.